# How to save a social media post as image programmatically to the gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, save, gallery, social-media

I want to create a feature in my app that will allow the user to save a social media post to the gallery. the idea is when the user presses share on the post, my app will appear in the share dialog, and by choosing the app, the image/gif/video will be automatically saved in the gallery. but the data that I receive from the intent is of type text/plain, naturally since the share feature provides a link to the post. however on 9gag and reddit for example, on the share dialog there's a "Save to Gallery" option that does save the post as a media file to the gallery. So my question is, is it possible to program a similar function in my app? what exactly do I need to do to achieve such a functionality? I am not asking for a code, just directions, where to look for an answer since i couldn't find anything on google about my topic.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: If the post is not inside your app then you can not capture post . If its showing inside your app then you can take drawing cache of view . For shring from other apps you will only get what other apps serves you in most cases its `text/plain` and `image` or link .

Comment: @ADM So if I understand correctly, the extra options on these social media apps to save posts to gallery are simply built in features that I cannot access from my app?

Comment: The data you will receive under `android.intent.action.SEND` is what you will get . You can not get extra data such as you want an screenshot of post. You will get the `meta` image with text You can handle the meta in your own way .  Just test it with facebook first to check .

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at intent filters https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive

The idea with these is you declare in your manifest the type of content your app can handle. Then, when a user shares a particular type of data, such as an image, from another app, then your app can be listed as an option to handle that image.